# Números primos - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo el siguiente código el cuál quiero adaptar para colocar números primos entre 1 y 1001. El detalle es que no encuentro como evitar el salto cuando no cumple las condiciones y por ende me dice undefined.

Probe colocando dos variables en el primer for, pero no me lo permite.
Los números que me muestra están bien, lo que está mal es dejar que escriba los undefined, porque está haciendo el salto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Array</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<script>
    let numeros = new Array (1001);
function primo()
 {
    for(let i=2; i < 1001 ; i++){
            let contador = 0;

            for (let j=1; j<=i; j++){
                if (i%j == 0)
                contador++;
            }
            if (contador==2){
                numeros[i] = i;       
            }

        }
        imprimirPrimo();
    }

function imprimirPrimo(){
    for (let i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += numeros[i];
        if(!isUltimoNumero(i, numeros)){
            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += ", ";
        }
    }
}
function isUltimoNumero(pos, array){
    if((pos + 1) != array.length){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
<body>
        <div id="contenidoCentro">
                <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                        <div id="ContenidoColumna1">
                            <h1 class="blanco">Array</h1>
            
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                            <div id="ContenidoColumna2">
                                <h2>(Array) Se necesita un sistema que almacena automáticamente todos los números primos desde el
                                        uno hasta el mil uno; recordando que un número primo es aquel que solamente es divisible entre
                                        uno y sí mismo.
                                        </h2>
                                <h3>Instrucciones: Haz click en el botón "Conoce los números primos entre 1 y 1001" y automáticamente se imprimirán.</em> </h3>
                                <center>
                                        
                                        <input type="button" onclick="primo()" value="Primo">
                                         
                                        <div id="resultado"></div>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                    </div>    
     
        
        </div>

        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Array</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<script>
    let numeros = new Array (1001);
function primo()
 {
    for(let i=2; i < 1001 ; i++){
            let contador = 0;

            for (let j=1; j<=i; j++){
                if (i%j == 0)
                contador++;
            }
            if (contador==2){
                numeros[i] = i;       
            }

        }
        imprimirPrimo();
    }

function imprimirPrimo(){
    for (let i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
        if(numeros[i] != null) {
          document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += numeros[i];
          if(!isUltimoNumero(i, numeros)){
              document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += ", ";
          }
        }
    }
}
function isUltimoNumero(pos, array){
    if((pos + 1) != array.length){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
<body>
        <div id="contenidoCentro">
                <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                        <div id="ContenidoColumna1">
                            <h1 class="blanco">Array</h1>
            
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                            <div id="ContenidoColumna2">
                                <h2>(Array) Se necesita un sistema que almacena automáticamente todos los números primos desde el
                                        uno hasta el mil uno; recordando que un número primo es aquel que solamente es divisible entre
                                        uno y sí mismo.
                                        </h2>
                                <h3>Instrucciones: Haz click en el botón "Conoce los números primos entre 1 y 1001" y automáticamente se imprimirán.</em> </h3>
                                <center>
                                        
                                        <input type="button" onclick="primo()" value="Primo">
                                         
                                        <div id="resultado"></div>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                    </div>    
     
        
        </div>

        
</body>
</html>
```

En la función `imprimirPrimo()`, en el momento de pintar el número puedes comprobar si la posición del `array` tiene o no tiene nada (es igual a `NULL`) y en caso afirmativo entonces lo pintas, en caso contrario no haces nada y pasas al siguiente.

**Solución 2**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Array</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<script>
    let numeros = new Array ();
function primo()
 {
    for(let i=2; i < 1001 ; i++){
            let contador = 0;

            for (let j=1; j<=i; j++){
                if (i%j == 0)
                contador++;
            }
            if (contador==2){
                numeros.push(i);  
            }

        }
        imprimirPrimo();
    }

function imprimirPrimo(){
    for (let i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += numeros[i];
        if(!isUltimoNumero(i, numeros)){
            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += ", ";
        }
    }
}
function isUltimoNumero(pos, array){
    if((pos + 1) != array.length){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
<body>
        <div id="contenidoCentro">
                <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                        <div id="ContenidoColumna1">
                            <h1 class="blanco">Array</h1>
            
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div id="ContenidoContenedor">
                            <div id="ContenidoColumna2">
                                <h2>(Array) Se necesita un sistema que almacena automáticamente todos los números primos desde el
                                        uno hasta el mil uno; recordando que un número primo es aquel que solamente es divisible entre
                                        uno y sí mismo.
                                        </h2>
                                <h3>Instrucciones: Haz click en el botón "Conoce los números primos entre 1 y 1001" y automáticamente se imprimirán.</em> </h3>
                                <center>
                                        
                                        <input type="button" onclick="primo()" value="Primo">
                                         
                                        <div id="resultado"></div>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                    </div>    
     
        
        </div>

        
</body>
</html>
```

Se podría optimizar, claro está. La primera manera que te propuse sería válida para mostrar un listado. Si luego quisieras operar con ese `array` de números primos lo más óptimo sería controlar la inserción del elemento. En el código inicial que presentas, se usa la `i` tanto como índice del `array` como para el valor, lo que provocaba que hubiese índices vacíos entre inserción e inserción.

Para solucionarlo opté por usar la función `push()`, que permite insertar un valor al final del `array`, de esa forma cada nueva inserción va a ir a continuación de la siguiente, no generando espacios vacíos.

Para hacerlo tuve que cambiar la manera de inicializar la variable `numeros` quitándole la longitud predeterminada, ya que en un `array` de longitud fija no es posible usar este método.

Comment: al hacerlo así no tendría un error de concepto? o sea, porque no tendría el vector de únicamente primos (pues hay espeacios en blanco). O igual estaría bien?

Comment: No, no sería un error de concepto. No es lo más limpio pero para imprimir un listado por pantalla era más que suficiente, ya que buscaba cambiar lo mínimo posible el código que nos presentas y además el avitar usar ninguna función propia de Javascript. He añadido una segunda solución en la respuesta para mantener el array más limpio.

Answer (score 5):

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto:

```js
var primos = [];
for(var n=3;n<=1002;n+=2) {
  if(primos.every(function(prime){return n%prime!=0})) {
    primos.push(n);
  }
}
primos.unshift(1);
console.log(primos);
```

Si te fijas todo estoy agregando en un array **primos**, espero te sirva.